# It`s possible to halt the system after DOS unspecified error

Tags: assembly, dos, tasm

I make a part of simple, DOS 3d renderer with basic projection algorithm
Note, that this render isn't a problem.
I know how to load PCX and display in the depth buffer
My question is about some code:

```
.model tiny
.386
.stack 400h

.data
    ErrMessage0 db 'Enough memory to allocate a depth buffer',0,'$'
    ErrMessage1 db "File 'BRICK.PCX' not found",0,'$'
    ErrMessage2 db 'Unsupported format of PCX',0,'$'
    ErrMessage3 db 'Enough memory to hold a image',0,'$'
.code
    main proc
    ;First we must resize PSP to enable any allocation
    ;PSP reserves all the memory
    ;ES=DS=PSP
    mov cx,ds
    mov ax,@data
    ;DS=data
    mov ds,ax
    mov ax,sp
    add ax,15
    shr ax,4
    mov bx,ss
    add bx,ax
    sub bx,cx
    mov ah,4ah
    int 21h
    ;This error is impossible to find in most DOS-es
    ;If you run program on
    ;buggy envirroment  next steps may cause jump to random location
    jc @@undc_dos_error



    ;... I plan to add cube render  
    ;after answer


    @@undc_dos_error:
    ;Now we don't use any DOS services because it's corrupted
    ;BIOS services always not corrupted
    sti
    xor ax,ax
    mov es,ax
    int 10h

    mov ax,b800h
    mov es,ax
    xor di,di
    mov ax,cs
    mov ds,ax
    mov si,offset ErrMessage4

    loop_text:
    mov al,word ptr ds:[si]
    cmp al,0
    je loop_text_end
    movsb
    jmp loop_text
    loop_text_end:
    hlt

    ErrMessage4: db  'DOS unspecified error, system halted '
    db 'Try CTRL+ALT+DELETE if int 09h is avaible',0

    endp
    end main
```

Is it possible to make this halt routine after error, which impossible to find.

Comment: I don't know the DOS internals but why such a catastrophic approach to a failed resize? [Ralf Brown's interrupts list document the error codes](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2936.htm) and I won't expect such call to destroy the computer, though I don't understand what you are resizing (the PSP?) and other things like a `.stack` directive in a COM file or an `hlt` with interrupts enabled.

Comment: I learned some assembly language and DOS rules, the PSP is program segment prefix, DS and ES point to PSP and program. Always PSP reserve all the memory and program must resize it to let any allocation.

Comment: If resize has an error it's a error in DOS internal resources. It's impossible to find this error in most DOS-es (See my comments in code).

Comment: Buggy environment is a definition of OS which have a lot of bugs and glitches. It's a risk, if you end program, it not jumps to caller but to random location.

Comment: Finally, it's a .exe program, not .com.

Comment: if it's an exe, then tiny is the wrong model for you

Comment: @Tommylee2k : If you build `tiny` model into an exe it is the same as `small` model.

Comment: "If resize has an error it's a error in DOS internal resources. It's impossible to find this error in most DOS-es" So it's an *implementation* detail you know about? If that's the case and you managed to get in control of execution, then resetting the video mode and displaying a string manually should work (if that's your question). Of course, you need to fix the assembly code as it contains errors.

Comment: If you are asking how to HLT after what you consider a catastrophic error  and your code actually is still running then you can simply do  `cli` `@@hltloop: hlt` `jmp @@hltloop`

Comment: If DOS is corrupt it probably has more to do with a program that corrupted it. If DOS is corrupt the entire system could be unstable. If the instability included a program overwriting the interrupt vector table then `int 10h` could go to some unexpected place in memory and not the code in the BIOS, In a corrupted system you can't necessarily rely on any `Int` call to work.